# Send data from Google Analytics 360 to Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hello I need to send data from Google Analytics 360 by python (or something else) script (using API) to Amazon S3 by weekly incremental updates of all user actions.

Because I had experience of data streaming from Google Analytics 360 to S3 only by using Google BigQuery. Now I need to do this without BigQuery

Could you please share some instructions/examples or own examples of your scripts for better understanding script view (structure) and using API by this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Analytics Reporting API**, here you can find official documentation with **Python**:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

Beware that unlike BigQuery where you can query the data as you like, with the API there are limits about **quota** and maximum **number of dimensions** in any query:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference